# TSQL to select 80% Male and 20% female population based on location

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which contains sample population data.

Here is the SQLFiddle session with schema and sample data.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e520/1

I want to use TSQL query to fetch data with following conditions:

1. Selected sample population should contain 80% Males & 20% females
2. Selected sample should have a uniform distribution based on City. This is to ensure that all cities are featured in the output with 80-20% male-female ratio (if possible) and the whole sample doesn't limit to one or two large cities. The overall 80-20% is primary requirement in comparison to the 80-20% within a city because there could be cities where it can't be met.
3. Selected should only contain individuals with age > 20 and salary > 10,000

I am unable to figure out on how to abide by the 80-20% distribution based on location.

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved and dont post images.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table t1
(
id int
)

insert into t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Comment: also please elaborate on this `Selected sample should have a uniform distribution based on location`

Comment: Thank you! I have made the required changes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the query below step-by-step, CTE-by-CTE and examine intermediate results to understand how it works.

`CTE_Male` returns a list of all Male rows with applied filter `Age > 20 and Salary > 10000`. `rnLocation` and `CountLocation` will be used to order these rows in a specific way. I want to list all cities, one-by-one, then again all cities, then again all cities, and so on. First will go the most common city. Like this: `ABCABCABCABABABAAA`. Then I'll take top `N` percent of these rows.

To get 80% of all Male rows I use `NTILE(5)` function. 80% is 4 out of 5 groups. So, the main `SELECT` has a filter `tile <= 4`. If you need to pick a different percentage adjust `NTILE` parameter.

Same approach works for Female rows, but since we need 20%, the filter is `tile <= 1`.

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Random_Data](
    [ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LoDallastion] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Age] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Salary] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[Random_Data] ([ID], [Type], [LoDallastion], [Age], [Salary]) VALUES 
 (N'1111', N'Male', N'Dallas', N'54', N'85421')
,(N'1112', N'Male', N'Dallas', N'18', N'164638')
,(N'1113', N'Male', N'Houston', N'35', N'155336')
,(N'1114', N'Male', N'Houston', N'24', N'50542')
,(N'1115', N'Male', N'Houston', N'26', N'155499')
,(N'1116', N'Male', N'Durham', N'24', N'31165')
,(N'1117', N'Male', N'Durham', N'15', N'90988')
,(N'1118', N'Male', N'Durham', N'39', N'150027')
,(N'1119', N'Female', N'Dallas', N'18', N'159713')
,(N'1120', N'Female', N'Dallas', N'23', N'62503')
,(N'1121', N'Female', N'Dallas', N'25', N'177185')
,(N'1122', N'Female', N'Dallas', N'15', N'193371')
,(N'1123', N'Female', N'Houston', N'74', N'31370')
,(N'1124', N'Female', N'Durham', N'46', N'97234')
,(N'1125', N'Female', N'Durham', N'53', N'182176')
,(N'1126', N'Female', N'Durham', N'28', N'148712')
,(N'1127', N'Female', N'Durham', N'42', N'176502')
,(N'1128', N'Female', N'Durham', N'64', N'62223')
,(N'1129', N'Female', N'Durham', N'75', N'189944')
,(N'1130', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'35', N'133312')
,(N'1131', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'63', N'95123')
,(N'1132', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'59', N'128996')
,(N'1133', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'34', N'92812')
,(N'1134', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'45', N'71514')
,(N'1135', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'55', N'59455')
,(N'1136', N'Female', N'San Jose', N'15', N'144925')
,(N'1137', N'Female', N'San Jose', N'39', N'96778')
,(N'1138', N'Female', N'San Jose', N'37', N'84800')
,(N'1139', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'71', N'188530')
,(N'1140', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'52', N'100521')
,(N'1141', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'38', N'78682')
,(N'1142', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'35', N'105433')
,(N'1143', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'37', N'37529')
,(N'1144', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'41', N'107591')
,(N'1145', N'Female', N'San Jose', N'75', N'94867')
,(N'1146', N'Female', N'San Jose', N'54', N'129194')
,(N'1147', N'Female', N'San Jose', N'65', N'64206')
,(N'1148', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'40', N'197250')
,(N'1149', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'20', N'131461')
,(N'1150', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'30', N'175853')
,(N'1151', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'27', N'171956')
,(N'1152', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'61', N'193986')
,(N'1153', N'Male', N'San Jose', N'25', N'107503')
,(N'1154', N'Female', N'Chica', N'28', N'57200');
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_Male
AS
(
    SELECT
        [ID]
        ,[Type]
        ,[LoDallastion]
        ,[Age]
        ,[Salary]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [LoDallastion] ORDER BY ID) AS rnLocation
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [LoDallastion]) AS CountLocation
    FROM
        [dbo].[Random_Data]
    WHERE
        [Type] = 'Male'
        AND [Age] > 20
        AND [Salary] > 10000
)
,CTE_MaleTiles
AS
(
    SELECT
        [ID]
        ,[Type]
        ,[LoDallastion]
        ,[Age]
        ,[Salary]
        ,CountLocation
        ,NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY rnLocation, CountLocation desc) AS tile
    FROM CTE_Male
)
,CTE_Female
AS
(
    SELECT
        [ID]
        ,[Type]
        ,[LoDallastion]
        ,[Age]
        ,[Salary]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [LoDallastion] ORDER BY ID) AS rnLocation
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [LoDallastion]) AS CountLocation
    FROM
        [dbo].[Random_Data]
    WHERE
        [Type] = 'Female'
        AND [Age] > 20
        AND [Salary] > 10000
)
,CTE_FemaleTiles
AS
(
    SELECT
        [ID]
        ,[Type]
        ,[LoDallastion]
        ,[Age]
        ,[Salary]
        ,CountLocation
        ,NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY rnLocation, CountLocation desc) AS tile
    FROM CTE_Female
)
SELECT 
    [ID]
    ,[Type]
    ,[LoDallastion]
    ,[Age]
    ,[Salary]
    ,CountLocation
FROM CTE_MaleTiles
WHERE tile <= 4

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    [ID]
    ,[Type]
    ,[LoDallastion]
    ,[Age]
    ,[Salary]
    ,CountLocation
FROM CTE_FemaleTiles
WHERE tile <= 1

ORDER BY [Type], CountLocation DESC, [LoDallastion];
```

**Result**

```
+------+--------+--------------+-----+--------+---------------+
|  ID  |  Type  | LoDallastion | Age | Salary | CountLocation |
+------+--------+--------------+-----+--------+---------------+
| 1124 | Female | Durham       |  46 |  97234 |             6 |
| 1137 | Female | San Jose     |  39 |  96778 |             5 |
| 1120 | Female | Dallas       |  23 |  62503 |             2 |
| 1130 | Male   | San Jose     |  35 | 133312 |            17 |
| 1131 | Male   | San Jose     |  63 |  95123 |            17 |
| 1132 | Male   | San Jose     |  59 | 128996 |            17 |
| 1133 | Male   | San Jose     |  34 |  92812 |            17 |
| 1134 | Male   | San Jose     |  45 |  71514 |            17 |
| 1135 | Male   | San Jose     |  55 |  59455 |            17 |
| 1139 | Male   | San Jose     |  71 | 188530 |            17 |
| 1140 | Male   | San Jose     |  52 | 100521 |            17 |
| 1141 | Male   | San Jose     |  38 |  78682 |            17 |
| 1142 | Male   | San Jose     |  35 | 105433 |            17 |
| 1143 | Male   | San Jose     |  37 |  37529 |            17 |
| 1144 | Male   | San Jose     |  41 | 107591 |            17 |
| 1148 | Male   | San Jose     |  40 | 197250 |            17 |
| 1115 | Male   | Houston      |  26 | 155499 |             3 |
| 1114 | Male   | Houston      |  24 |  50542 |             3 |
| 1113 | Male   | Houston      |  35 | 155336 |             3 |
| 1116 | Male   | Durham       |  24 |  31165 |             2 |
| 1118 | Male   | Durham       |  39 | 150027 |             2 |
| 1111 | Male   | Dallas       |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
+------+--------+--------------+-----+--------+---------------+
```

There are 15 Female rows with `Age > 20` and `Salary > 10000`. 20% out of 15 is 3. End result has 3 Female rows.

There are 23 Male rows with `Age > 20` and `Salary > 10000`. 80% out of 23 is 18.4. End result has 19 Male rows.

End result has rows from as many cities as possible.

**Second example**

```
INSERT [dbo].[Random_Data] ([ID], [Type], [LoDallastion], [Age], [Salary]) VALUES 
(N'1111', N'Male', N'A', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'1112', N'Male', N'B', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'1113', N'Male', N'C', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'1114', N'Male', N'D', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'1115', N'Male', N'E', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'1116', N'Male', N'F', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'1117', N'Male', N'G', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'1118', N'Male', N'H', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'1119', N'Male', N'I', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'1120', N'Male', N'J', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'2111', N'Female', N'A', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'2112', N'Female', N'B', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'2113', N'Female', N'C', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'2114', N'Female', N'D', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'2115', N'Female', N'E', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'2116', N'Female', N'F', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'2117', N'Female', N'G', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'2118', N'Female', N'H', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'2119', N'Female', N'I', N'54', N'85421'),
(N'2120', N'Female', N'J', N'54', N'85421');
```

There are 10 cities with one Male and one Female row in each city.
Obviously, it is not possible to get 80-20 split for any given city, but the overall result of the query below has 80-20 split.

**Result**

```
+------+--------+--------------+-----+--------+---------------+
|  ID  |  Type  | LoDallastion | Age | Salary | CountLocation |
+------+--------+--------------+-----+--------+---------------+
| 2111 | Female | A            |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
| 2112 | Female | B            |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
| 1111 | Male   | A            |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
| 1112 | Male   | B            |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
| 1113 | Male   | C            |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
| 1114 | Male   | D            |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
| 1115 | Male   | E            |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
| 1116 | Male   | F            |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
| 1117 | Male   | G            |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
| 1118 | Male   | H            |  54 |  85421 |             1 |
+------+--------+--------------+-----+--------+---------------+
```

Comment: For San Jose location we have total 22 (17M + 5F) records. so as per the requirement we need to select 20% female i.e 22 * 0.2 = 4 or 5 from San Jose location itself . so for overall data 15 *0.2 = 3 is ok however it is not satisfying the  80-20% requirement for every city basis.

Comment: @RahulRichhariya, I was focusing on the first condition `Selected sample population should contain 80% Males & 20% females` and then trying to add as many cities to the result set as possible. It looks like you were focusing on getting 80-20 split for each city first. The question says `The overall 80-20% is primary requirement in comparison to the 80-20% within a city because there could be cities where it can't be met.` Try the second example that I added to this answer with your query. In my test of your query it didn't return Female rows at all.

Comment: yes , because 20% of each city is falling below 1. So in your second example if i  replace all the males with female except first row you will get 4 females and 1 male in output.  just opposite of your expectation . As i mentioned in one of my comment we will get proper value when we have a sizable sample size (at least few 10+ record per city). This is a perfect example of - how sample size can affect Statistical study.

Comment: @RahulRichhariya, well, 4 females out of 19 total is as closest to 20% as you can get. 1 male out of 1 male total is as closest to 80% as you can get. That's the difference of my approach. It returns proportion of the total regardless of cities. And only then picks cities. You start with cities and in your last example your code returns only one row with Male, even though there are 19 total rows with Female. I think, there is no point arguing here, OP should clarify the question. Until the question is clarified any of our guesses is just a guess.

Comment: Please read the heading of the question - "TSQL to select 80% Male and 20% female population based on location " .  So the objective is - the output should have 80% male and 20% female in final output based on city.

Comment: I chose Vladimir's answer because it keeps the primary requirement. I guess my question has some ambiguity which leaves the scope of different results. Thanks to both of you for enriching discussion and great answers.

Answer (score 0):

I used AVG to get uniform distribution, however you can use standard deviation (STDEV) & AVG to improve your distribution-

```
Create table #Source  (
ID  int ,
Type  char(6) ,
Location Varchar(50) ,
Age tinyint,
Salary int
) 
go

insert into  #Source 
 select 1, 'Male' , 'Dallas' , 51,11000
 union all select 2, 'Male' , 'Dallas' , 42,8000
 union all select 3, 'Male' , 'Dallas' , 52,20000
 union all select 4, 'Male' , 'Houston' , 34,11000
 union all select 5, 'Male' , 'Houston' , 18,9000
 union all select 6, 'Male' , 'Houston' , 32,15000
 union all select 7, 'Male' , 'Houston' , 41,22000
 union all select 8, 'Male' , 'Houston' , 60,11000
 union all select 9, 'Male' , 'Durham' , 55,8000
 union all select 10, 'Male' , 'Durham' , 19,20000
 union all select 11, 'Male' , 'Durham' , 20,11000
 union all select 12, 'Male' , 'Durham' , 51,9000
 union all select 13, 'Female' , 'Dallas' , 42,15000
 union all select 14, 'Female' , 'Dallas' , 52,22000
 union all select 15, 'Female' , 'Dallas' , 34,11000
 union all select 16, 'Female' , 'Houston' , 18,8000
 union all select 17, 'Female' , 'Houston' , 32,20000
 union all select 18, 'Female' , 'Houston' , 41,11000
 union all select 19, 'Female' , 'Houston' , 60,9000
 union all select 20, 'Female' , 'Houston' , 55,15000
 union all select 21, 'Female' , 'Durham' , 19,22000
 union all select 22, 'Female' , 'Durham' , 20,11000
 union all select 23, 'Female' , 'Durham' , 55,8000


 select * , 
 ROW_NUMBER ()   over( partition by Location order by ID )   as RowNum_1 , -- This will be used to get uniform distribution based on location 
 ROW_NUMBER () over( partition by Location , Type order by Location , Type) RowNum_2, --  This will be used to get 80% Males & 20% females
 count (*)  over( partition by Location  ) * 0.8 as [80%] , -- value of 80% based on location 
 count (*)  over( partition by Location  ) * 0.2  as [20%] -- value of 20% based on location 
into #dest
 from #Source
 where Age>20 and Salary >10000
 order by Location , Type


 declare @AvgRowPerLocation int  
 select  @AvgRowPerLocation = COUNT(*)/count(distinct Location)  from #dest 

 select * from #dest
 where  RowNum_1 <= @AvgRowPerLocation   -- this will make sure we are getting almost equal row from each location ** you can remove this if you have small amount of data.
 and ( ( RowNum_2 <= [80%] and Type = 'Male' ) 
 or (RowNum_2 <= [20%] and Type = 'Female') )
```

Comment: Your query returns 2 rows with Female type and 12 rows with Male type (given the sample data from the SQLFiddle in the question). It doesn't seem correct. There are 23 Male rows in the sample data that satisfy the Age and Salary filter criteria, so end result should have around 23 * 0.8 = 18.4 Male rows. Similarly, there are 15 Female rows and 20% of 15 is 3.

Comment: Please ignore previous comment. If you remove below condition form last query you will get the result -   
   where  RowNum_1 <= @AvgRowPerLocation  . However you have one additional requirement - " the whole sample doesn't limit to one or two large cities" . so the above condition will make sure you are not taking huge amount of data from one city. as you can see in sample data most of the data (around 50%) belongs to "San Jose" . If i remove above condition you will get 21 rows from one city.  So the above condition will work properly when you have huge amount of data.